# Is 1 bigger than 0.99999...... or they are equal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is question which always disturbs me. Could somebody help me?

> Is 1 bigger than 0.99999...... or they are equal?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equal. Suppose not. Then $|1-0.\dot{9}|=c>0$. However, $|1-0.\dot{9}|$ is less than any given positive number, this is not possible as $c$ is a fixed positive number.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$10 \cdot 0.(9) = 9.(9)$